# How to build my GLMM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm

I am basically trying to build a model for analyzing my data. I put one termite on the leaf and another one on the inflorescences (in the same plant) and I did this in two different plant species. I observed the abundance of ants and how much time ants took to find the termite. I repeated this 30 times in different plants and wait 15 min maximum.

I would like to know if time is interfered by plant, place an/or abundance. The problem is I don't know how to build the model and which function is more appropriate. Firstly, I had thought that place is nested within plant and model could be something like:

```
model<-lmer(time~plant/place + (1|abund), data=dados)

       plant place                ant behav time abund
1 Palicourea inflo Camponotus crassus   sim    5     2
2 Palicourea inflo Camponotus crassus   sim  120     2
3 Palicourea inflo Camponotus crassus   sim    6     2
4 Palicourea leaf             nenhuma   nao  900     0
5    Miconia leaf  Camponotus crassus   sim  240     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good idea, but you've specified the model incorrectly. The fixed-effect structure is specified first, and then the random-effects structure is specified in the parentheses.

Let's say we have a dependent variable (`y`), an independent variable (`x`), and a grouping variable (`id`) in our data (`dat`). If we want a saturated fixed- and random-effect structure, we would specify:

```
lmer(y ~ x + (1 + x|id), dat)
```

So if you are trying to see if `abund` predicts `time`, and is nested within `plant` and `place`, you could specify:

```
lmer(time ~ abund + (1|place/plant), dados)
```

Lots of great code examples are [here.](http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer)